# Travelport uAPI SoapClient response issue

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl, travelport-api

i am new to travelport universal api. i receive response from api. I perform LOW FARE SEARCH and in response the fare information and the flight information return in two different list.the problem is that i don't find any relationship in these LIST's. and also WHAT IS THE BEST WAY TO DECODE THE WSDL RESPONSE.  i am using WSDL below is my code

```
string TargetBranch = "P7004961";
string OriginApplication = "uAPI";
string Origin="DXB";
string   Destination="LHR";
string Departuredate = "2014-03-25T00:00:00";
string FlightStatus = "One-way";
string url = "https://americas-uapi.copy-webservices.travelport.com/B2BGateway/connect/uAPI/AirService";
string ReturnDate = "2014-04-05T00:00:00";
string UserName = "Universal API/uAPI6035036525-8ff7f8fc", Password = "DSXSEDn3fme9d6m2DfKP5rEaW";
LowFareSearchReq req = new LowFareSearchReq();
req.TargetBranch = TargetBranch;
BillingPointOfSaleInfo biPOS = new BillingPointOfSaleInfo();
biPOS.OriginApplication = OriginApplication;
req.BillingPointOfSaleInfo = biPOS;
/////////// Origin to Destination////////////////
SearchAirLeg airLeg = new SearchAirLeg();
Airport fromAirPort = new Airport() { Code = Origin };
typeSearchLocation fromTypLoc = new typeSearchLocation() { Item = fromAirPort };
airLeg.SearchOrigin = new typeSearchLocation[1] { fromTypLoc };
Airport toAirPort = new Airport() { Code = Destination };
typeSearchLocation toTypLoc = new typeSearchLocation() { Item = toAirPort };
airLeg.SearchDestination = new typeSearchLocation[1] { toTypLoc };        
typeTimeSpec origDep = new typeTimeSpec() { PreferredTime = Departuredate };
airLeg.Items = new typeTimeSpec[1] { origDep };
/////////////////// Destination to Origin ////////////////////
SearchAirLeg returnLeg = new SearchAirLeg();
Airport RetfromAirport = new Airport() { Code = Destination };
typeSearchLocation fromLocation = new typeSearchLocation() { Item = RetfromAirport };
returnLeg.SearchOrigin = new typeSearchLocation[1] { fromLocation };
Airport retToAirpot = new Airport() { Code = Origin };
typeSearchLocation tolocation = new typeSearchLocation() { Item = retToAirpot };
returnLeg.SearchDestination = new typeSearchLocation[1] { tolocation };
typeTimeSpec retdate = new typeTimeSpec() { PreferredTime = ReturnDate };
returnLeg.Items = new typeTimeSpec[1] { retdate };
///////// checking for one way or return//////////////////////////
if (FlightStatus == "One-way")
{
    req.Items = new object[] { airLeg };
}
else
{
    req.Items = new object[] { airLeg, returnLeg };
}       
AirSearchModifiers AirsearchModifier = new AirSearchModifiers()
{
    DistanceType = typeDistance.KM,
    IncludeFlightDetails = true,
    PreferNonStop = true,
    MaxSolutions = "300",
    PreferredProviders=  new Provider[1]{ new Provider(){ Code="1G"}}
};
req.AirSearchModifiers = AirsearchModifier;
SearchPassenger pass1 = new SearchPassenger() { Code = "ADT" };
req.SearchPassenger = new SearchPassenger[] { pass1 };
string Currency = "PKR";
AirPricingModifiers AirPriceMode = new AirPricingModifiers() { CurrencyType = Currency, };
req.AirPricingModifiers = AirPriceMode;
LowFareSearchRsp response = new LowFareSearchRsp();
AirLowFareSearchBinding binding = new AirLowFareSearchBinding();
binding.Url = url;
binding.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

response = binding.service(req);
```

Comment: What's your exact problem? What is the type of `response`?

Comment: the response is consist of multiple lists and the and i want to know what is the best ways to decode these list or convert it to datatable or dataset

Comment: Why convert them? Just deal with them as-is.

Comment: i have to find to find relationship as i said the arraylist's have different length and also i am haven't use arraylist

Comment: You should be more clear about what your problem is. If there is a relationship between two lists, then surely the service must return sufficient information for you to clearly determine the relationship. One list must contain a key field from another list, for instance. Your question, as you have written it, does not describe the problem you are having. You should edit your question and add a clear statement of the problem. As it is, it sounds like you don't even know how to get the properties of the result object.

Comment: air solution list which contain the fare information contain property of airsegmetref which is null as well as both of the arraylist contain a key property but the don't match with each other

Comment: But how could anyone here help you with that? You should contact the service authors. Do they have no example code?

Comment: Do you know about https://developer.travelport.com/app/developer-network/universal-api?

Comment: yeah i have read that all they also provide connection class [http://demo.travelportuniversalapi.com/(S(fxe3weiq2wbblzrtuqj4njwr))/Home/SampleCode] i also tryed that but on line
   Stream stream = serverRequest.GetRequestStream();
it give in exception which is "This stream does not support seek operations." and the webresponse trun an exception of bad request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all.Finally i found result which is below quit easy in fact In the LowFareSearch response you get back among other info a list of AirSegments and a list of AirPricingSolutions. Each AirPricingSolution contains AirPricingInfo with the applicable SegmentRef keys and BookingCode info. Each SegmentRef key corresponds to a flight in the AirSegment list. This is how you know which flights (AirSegments) correspond to a specific price (AirPricingSolution).